# VB NET - ZLIB - Uncompress a stream

Tags: vb.net, stream, zlib

I have a little class that can uncompress a byte array with zlib. Here it is :

```
 <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("zlib1.DLL", CallingConvention:=Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint:="compress2", charset:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)> _
    Private Shared Function CompressByteArray2(ByVal dest As Byte(), ByRef destLen As Integer, ByVal src As Byte(), ByVal srcLen As Integer, ByVal level As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Public Shared Function DeCompressBytes(ByVal Bytes() As Byte) As Byte()

        Dim OrigSize As Integer = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Bytes, 0)
        Dim Data(Bytes.Length - 5) As Byte
        Array.Copy(Bytes, 4, Data, 0, Bytes.Length - 4)

        Dim DLLfunctionResult As Integer

        Dim bResult(CInt(OrigSize + (OrigSize * 0.01) + 12)) As Byte

        DLLfunctionResult = UncompressByteArray(bResult, OrigSize, Data, Data.Length)

        If DLLfunctionResult = 0 Then
            ReDim Preserve bResult(OrigSize - 1)
            Return bResult
        Else
            Return Bytes
        End If

    End Function
```

It Works, no problem.
I would like to know if it's possible to uncompress from a stream instead of a byte array. Because right now, I  have to read the stream and put it in a variable, then uncompress it and put the new result in a variable. The purpose is to accelerate the process. Maybe it will not do that, but I would still like to know about

(French here, sorry for my english)

Comment: Maybe try using [`DeflateStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of PInvoking the native DLL directly - I think that uses the same algorithm, and the docs say "Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, the DeflateStream class uses the zlib library" so it may even be the same library underneath.

Comment: Oups, I forgot to say : .NET 4.0

Comment: DeflateStream is available since .NET 2.0, but I assume from that statement in the docs that prior to .NET 4.5 it used a custom implementation of the deflate algorithm.  Probably still worth seeing if it can handle your data.

Comment: I tried it some time ago. It was waaaay slower.